# App crashes everytime i press result button

Tags: android, calculator

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                      Process: com.vineet.calculator, PID: 29435
                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Boolean.`enter code here`booleanValue()' on a null object reference
                          at com.vineet.calculator.MainActivity$16.onClick(MainActivity.java:177)
                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                          at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
    Application terminated.

```
**Activity.java**

package com.vineet.calculator;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button btn0;
    Button btn1;
    Button btn2;
    Button btn3;
    Button btn4;
    Button btn5;
    Button btn6;
    Button btn7;
    Button btn8;
    Button btn9;
    Button btnResult;
    Button btnClear;
    Button btnExit;

    Button btnAdd;
    Button btnSub;
    Button btnMul;
    Button btnDiv;

    EditText etNumber;
    TextView tvAnswer;

    int val1, val2;
    Boolean boolMul, boolAdd, boolSub, boolDiv;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn0 = findViewById(R.id.btn0);
        btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn3 = findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        btn4 = findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        btn5 = findViewById(R.id.btn5);
        btn6 = findViewById(R.id.btn6);
        btn7 = findViewById(R.id.btn7);
        btn8 = findViewById(R.id.btn8);
        btn9 = findViewById(R.id.btn9);
        btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnSub = findViewById(R.id.btnSub);
        btnMul = findViewById(R.id.btnMul);
        btnDiv = findViewById(R.id.btnDiv);
        btnResult = findViewById(R.id.btnResult);
        btnClear = findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
        btnExit = findViewById(R.id.btnExit);
        etNumber = findViewById(R.id.etNumber);
        tvAnswer = findViewById(R.id.tvAnswer);


        btn0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                etNumber.setText(etNumber.getText()+"0");
            }
        });
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                etNumber.setText(etNumber.getText()+"1");
            }
        });
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                etNumber.setText(etNumber.getText()+"2");
            }
        });
        btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                etNumber.setText(etNumber.getText()+"3");
            }
        });
        btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                etNumber.setText(etNumber.getText()+"4");
            }
        });
        btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                etNumber.setText(etNumber.getText()+"5");
            }
        });
        btn6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                etNumber.setText(etNumber.getText()+"6");
            }
        });
        btn7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                etNumber.setText(etNumber.getText()+"7");
            }
        });
        btn8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                etNumber.setText(etNumber.getText()+"8");
            }
        });
        btn9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                etNumber.setText(etNumber.getText()+"9");
            }
        });
        btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                etNumber.setText("");
                tvAnswer.setText("");
            }
        });


        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                val1 = Integer.valueOf(etNumber.getText().toString());
                boolAdd = true;
                etNumber.setText(null);
            }
        });

        btnSub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                val1 = Integer.valueOf(etNumber.getText().toString());
                boolSub = true;
                etNumber.setText(null);
            }
        });

        btnMul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                val1 = Integer.valueOf(etNumber.getText().toString());
                boolMul = true;
                etNumber.setText("");
            }
        });

        btnDiv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                val1 = Integer.valueOf(etNumber.getText().toString());
                boolDiv = true;
                etNumber.setText("");
            }
        });

        btnResult.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                val2 = Integer.valueOf(etNumber.getText().toString());

                if(boolAdd == true){
                    tvAnswer.setText(val1 + val2+"");
                    boolAdd = false;
                }
                if(boolSub == true){
                    tvAnswer.setText(val1 - val2 + "");
                    boolSub = false;
                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: why `if(boolAdd == true)`? Why not `if(boolAdd)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `Boolean`(non primitive data type) instead of `boolean`.

You must initialize Boolean to use :

```
Boolean boolMul = new Boolean(false);
```

Similarly initialize all your Boolean variables or use boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Use "boolean" instead of "Boolean". A Boolean is a class and it wraps a value of the primitive type boolean in an object. Avoid using it because it takes more memory as compare to primitive type.

Also instead of writing sooo many setOnclickListeners implement View.OnClickListener in MainActivity and use Switch case to handle button clicks.